.Net Maui ZXing minSDKVersion

This line of code is updating it self to 19, when it has to be above 21, when I use the Camera permissions in the Android Manifest. If I disable the camera permission it fixes the issue, but i need to be using it. I have looked at some similar problems, but I can not find the fix to make it stop updating it self. I'm using the camera for Zxing barcode scanning.
From what i have found on similar issues I saw that some people had an extra minSdkVersion that was messing with it, but mine does not contain that.
